# OpenLayers, problem with WFS service and "outputFormat"

Tags: openlayers, layers, wfs, mapping

I have a service and I tried to paint his layer on my map:

```
http://www.ign.es/wfs-inspire/unidades-administrativas?REQUEST=GetFeature&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&COUNT=1&srsName=EPSG:3857&TYPENAMES=au:AdministrativeBoundary


WFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: 'http://www.ign.es/wfs-inspire/unidades-administrativas?REQUEST=GetFeature&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&COUNT=1&srsName=EPSG:3857&TYPENAMES=au:AdministrativeBoundary'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
            width: 2
        })
})
```

¿is it possible? I don't see the geometries in the map. I think the problem is "outputFormat", is not possible get "outputFormat=application/json"

Answer (score 2):

> is not possible get "outputFormat=application/json"

It is not possible in the service you list.  The service GetCapabilities response tells you what output formats are available:

> http://www.ign.es/wfs-inspire/unidades-administrativas?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities

```
<ows:Parameter name="outputFormat">
    <ows:AllowedValues>
        <ows:Value>text/xml; subtype=gml/3.2.1</ows:Value>
        <ows:Value>application/gml+xml; version=3.2</ows:Value>
        <ows:Value>text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1</ows:Value>
        <ows:Value>text/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2</ows:Value>
    </ows:AllowedValues>
</ows:Parameter>
```

and `application/json` is not available

Furthermore the service here appears to be a complex features WFS

see:

> http://contenido.ign.es/wfs-inspire/unidades-administrativas?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAME=au:AdministrativeBoundary

and:

> http://contenido.ign.es/wfs-inspire/unidades-administrativas?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAME=au:AdministrativeBoundary&count=1&

and AFAIK OpenLayers can't handle complex features

Comment: is it possible paint the layer on the map?

Comment: It should be possible, since OpenLayers support GML formats 2, 3, and 3.2, but I couldn't get it working with this particular WFS service.